# How to differentiate AD(System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException) exceptions which is using kerberos authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, kerberos, ntlm

We are using below code to authenticate user credentials,

```
string domainAndUsername = this.activeDirectoryConfiguration.Domain + @"\" + username;    
        DirectoryEntry entry = null;
        try
        {
            entry = new DirectoryEntry(
                this.activeDirectoryConfiguration.LdapPath,
                domainAndUsername,
                password);

            // Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.
            object nativeObject = entry.NativeObject;

            if (nativeObject == null)
            {
                return AuthenticationDetails.InvalidCredentials;
            }
        }
        catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException directoryServicesComException)
        {
            return this.CheckErrorResponse(username, directoryServicesComException);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (entry != null)
            {
                entry.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

This code works fine when using NTLM authentication. Here we are checking error code we get from the 'DirectoryServicesCOMException' to identify whether account is locked or disabled or if the password is expired.

In our production environment, kerberos authentication is used where this code is failing. It throws System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException which doesn't have detailed description about the failure. Every time it just throws
Message=Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Can anyone suggest why isn't Kerberos giving detailed exception or is there any way to identify various login failures while using kerberos?

Comment: but in this you are making a new entry not checking against it.. confused as

Comment: I am creating a new directory entry to search the user.